# R: Getting NA while using sapply within apply

Tags: r, apply, sapply

I am getting NAs when running code below on a timeseries object. Effectively, I am trying to apply upDownCapture on each column of data with an expanding window. I achieve this by using sapply and seq_along.

```
apply(data[,1:5],2, function(x) unlist(sapply(seq_along(x), function(i) upDownCapture(x[i:length(x)],idx[i:length(x)],12,'b'))))
```

where

```
   upDownCapture <- function(y,x,minLen,upOrDown)
        {
          if(upOrDown == "u")
          {
            dataset <- na.omit(merge(x[x>0],y[x>0]))
          } else if(upOrDown == "d"){
            dataset <- na.omit(merge(x[x<0],y[x<0]))
          } else dataset <- na.omit(merge(x,y))

          ## running a linear regression and getting slope
          if(dim(dataset)[1] >= minLen){
            slope <- lm(dataset[,2]~dataset[,1])$coefficients[[2]]
          }else slope <- NA
          return(slope)
        }
```

I have similar apply setups eg below and they seem to be working fine

```
as.zoo(apply(excessReturns,2, function(x) {sapply(seq_along(x), function(i) sd(x[i:length(x)],na.rm = TRUE))}),order.by = index(data))
```

I am not able to understand what information is getting lost from apply to sapply for updowncapture function. I ran the sapply and upDownCapture by itself on data and they seem to be working fine.

Dataset looks like

```
 head(Data[,1])
                                                              A
1997-01-31                                                      -0.0002
1997-02-28                                                      -0.0428
1997-03-31                                                       0.0827
1997-04-30                                                       NA
1997-05-31                                                       0.0351
1997-06-30                                                       0.0749

head(idx)
                Russell 1000
1997-01-31      0.00384
1997-02-28     -0.04504
1997-03-31      0.05411
1997-04-30      0.06404
1997-05-31      0.04144
1997-06-30      0.08183
```

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Can you provide sample data to make this reproducible?

Comment: Your `apply` passes columns of a data.frame (or matrix) to your anonymous `function(x)`, which is passed to sapply, which turns the input into `1:length(that column)`, which then is passed to your anonymous `function(i)`. At this step, you are (probably unintentionally) abusing R's scoping rule by trying to subset some element from x, which is never passed to your anonymous function. x is somewhere in your global environment. Also All the x and y passed to your `upDownCapture` are identical for every apply iteration. What is x? paste dput(head(x)) here if you can.

Comment: @Vlo - please see structure(c(-2e-04, -0.0428, 0.0827, 0.0468, 0.0351, 0.0749), class = c("xts", 
"zoo"), .indexCLASS = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tclass = "Date", tzone = "UTC", index = structure(c(854668800, 
857088000, 859766400, 862358400, 865036800, 867628800), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(6L, 
1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "A"))                                                                                          there are some NAs in the data so its not identical for each iteration.

Comment: @JasonAizkalns - added sample data, thanks

Comment: I misread `i` as `1`. Your `x, and `y` are different every iteration. Are you sure that `(dim(dataset)[1] >= minLen)` condition is met during every run? Also what is the relationship between x and `data`. It seems that the numeric value within `data` doesn't matter one bit.

Comment: @Vlo The condition     
         (dim(dataset)[1] >= minLen) 
will not be met in every iteration. x is one column of data. Effectively, I am trying to apply upDownCapture function to an expanding window of each column of x, just like here
        apply(excessReturns,2, function(x) {sapply(seq_along(x), function(i) sd(x[i:length(x)],na.rm = TRUE))})

Comment: Asking you to check if the conditions are met every iteration, part of the debugging process. Seeing how your code can return `NA` if the condition is not met, perhaps it would be good to check this condition. Insert a `browser` before the condition line.

Comment: @Vlo - I checked data inside upDownCapture. When doing a merge at 
    na.omit(merge(x[x>0],y[x>0]))
it's padding x and y with NAs eg 
    2015-04-30     0.013083        NA
    2015-04-30           NA  0.025366